# POST url parameter understanding

Tags: php, html, post, get

I have got API like below for my android application. I am able to test it using postman app for chrome.

```
    <?php
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    require_once 'include/utility.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $response = array("error" => FALSE);

    if (isset($_POST['membership']) && isset($_POST['orderid']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $time = getDatetimeNow();
        $membership = $_POST["membership"];
        $orderid    = $_POST["orderid"];
        $email      = $_POST["email"];

        $response = $db->premium($membership, $orderid, $email, $time);   
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // required post params is missing
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email, orderid and membership are missing!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

its working fine and have not any issue but I have some similar api and I want test it direct from browser but I am getting parameter missing error in it.

I am trying it like below URL

```
https://example.com/api/premium.php?membership=1&orderid=123&email=myemail@mail.com
```

its give me errr that parameter is missing. Anyone can please suggest me how can I check it using browser instead of postman etc?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to send data via **GET** request, but it's not the same as **POST**. 
You cannot just put variables in URL and send it like POST data, because POST data sends in body or request. You can [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

If you want to send data via POST, you can create a HTMJL page with a small form and send it by POST, for example:

```
<form action="https://example.com/api/premium.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="membership" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="orderid" value="123">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="myemail@mail.com">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok Thanks!  I got it.

Comment: Alternatively, OP could change their code from `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` and use either GET or POST parameters

Comment: @Phil there any side effect of using $_REQUEST?

Comment: @PritiPatel it includes merged data from `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`. The order of precedence is determined by environment configuration so you may get varying results, depending on where you execute it

Answer (score 0):

You can not send email as a query string becaues Reserved characters in URLs must be encoded to be valid, or they are ambiguous and might be used for their reserved purposes in the URL.  @ is a reserved character, and must be encoded as %40.

PHP decodes this for you. It's transparent to you, and you don't even have to worry about it.